# Is there a way to download a PHP/ASP/whatever source code without processing it, as plain text?

Tags: http, web, security

Suppose the URL http://example.com/test.php. If I type this URL on the browser address bar, the PHP code is executed, and its output is returned to me. Fine. But, what if instead of executing it, I wanted to view it's source as plain text. Is there a a way to issue such request?

I believe that there must be some way, and my concern is that some outsider could retrieve sensitive code, such as configurations file, by guessing it's location. For example, Joomla instalations have a `configuration.php` on it's root folder. If someone retrieves such file as plain text, then these database credentials have been seriously compromised. Obviously, this could be prevented with proper permissions, but it's just too common to just issue `0777` as everything permissions and forgetting about access denials.

Comment: If the server is configured properly, no, there is no way to download the code instead of executing it.

Comment: Someone can retrieve such file as plain text ONLY IF the credentials have already been compromised. I mean, you can rest assured the source can not be displayed through browser (if php is properly working that is!) but other users accessing your files because file permissions? That is very much possible.

Comment: @Wooble but about what configs are you talking about? Could you use Apache as an example?

Comment: Even if the webserver is configured really badly, the it will only execute the PHP **OR** serve it up as text. Not both at the same time. And the latter scenario should be very evident. AFAIK, this is the case for all web development languages (albeit that compiled code is a bit harder to read).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For PHP: if properly configured, there is no way to download it. File permissions won't help either way, as the webserver needs to be able to read the files, and that's the one serving contents. However. a webserver *can* for instance be configured to serve them with `x-httpd-php-source`, or the PHP/webserver configuration may be broken. Which is why files which don't need direct access (db config, class definitions, etc.) *should* be *outside* the document root, so there is no way those files will get served by accident even when the webserver config is incorrect / failing. If your current hoster does not allow you to store files outside the document root, switch hosting a.s.a.p.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to issue such request that downloads the source code of `http://example.com/test.php` if the server is configured to provide a URL to do so. Usually it isn't, so usually there is no way to issue such a request.